# Elevation in CSS using Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, polymer

Is it possible to use *elevation* as a css property for a *paper-element* in Polymer 1.0.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `@apply(--shadow-elevation-2dp);`